# ParametricNDSolve Behaviour

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation, parametric-functions

Let's consider a set of equations with initial conditions. Since equations of my interest are complicated, I want to solve those with ParametricNDSolve.
For simplicity let's discuss linear equations though.

```
testEquations = {x'[t] == a, y'[t] == b, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0};
xy = ParametricNDSolveValue[testEquations, {x, y}, {t, -10, 10}, {a, b, x0, y0}];
```

The result I expect is a list of 2 interpolating functions (one for x, one for y), which should return me functions of t after substituting the parameters.
Now if we substitute something

```
subs = {a -> 1, b -> 1, x0 -> 1, y0 -> 2};
xy[a, b, x0, y0][[1]][t] /. subs
```

The output is

```
1[t]
```

The same output is for `xy[a, b, x0, y0][[2]][t]`
and

```
xy[a, b, x0, y0][[1]] /. subs
```

Returns just `1`.
In addition,

```
xy[1, 1, 1, 1][[1]][0] /. subs
```

Gives output

```
ParametricNDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`. >>
1[0]
```

Does anyone know what did I miss?
I am using Mathematica 10.3.1

Comment: `xy[a, b, x0, y0][[1]][t]` gives `a[t]`, and this is the first that is evaluated. Then you apply the rules on this output - it's about the order of evaluation (like differentation - $f'(2)$ doesn't mean to differentiate $f(2)$). Why not just `Set` the values of parameters?

Comment: Oh, now I see it.
I didn't use Set on the parameters because later I will need to use NonlinearModelFit, which also gives an error, so I tried to find a flaw in this piece of code first. 
The error message is looking similar to the output which I obtained by substitution and reads as  
'"The function value {1.[0.],-1.+1.[1.],-1.+1.[0.],-2.+1.[1.]} is not \
a list of real numbers with dimensions {4} at {b,c,n0,p0} = \
{1.,1.,1.,2.}."'
May be I will have to open another question to be more specific. 
Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [corey979](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/22013/corey979), this is a matter of evaluation order. The easiest workaround is probably:

```
Unevaluated@xy[a, b, x0, y0][[1]][t] /. subs
```

or

```
Hold@xy[a, b, x0, y0][[1]][t] /. subs // ReleaseHold
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `xy[a, b, x0, y0][[1]][t]` returns `a[t]` unless all the parameters are numbers.

The easiest way to avoid it, as it seems to me, is to use ParametricNDSolveValue 2 times to obtain each of the functions of interest, instead of trying to return a list of functions.

```
xSol = ParametricNDSolveValue[testEquations, x, {t, -10, 10}, {a, b, x0, y0}];
ySol = ParametricNDSolveValue[testEquations, y, {t, -10, 10}, {a, b, x0, y0}];
```